# How can the title "13" be so common?

Tags: trademark

According to [the Wikipedia disambiguation page for 13](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/13), there are nineteen albums, four songs, two movies, two novels, a card game, a manga, a musical and a play all titled "13", not counting stylizations or alternate forms such as "Thirteen", "13th", "Number 13" or "XIII".

Wouldn't there be some trademark issues?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot copyright a word or name in and of itself, so you can't sue someone for having a novel titled 13 so long as their novel is distinct from your own.   Trademarks can use certain words or word combinations, but often in a way that is stylized or symbolic of a particular unique style and may include font, coloring, and other unique artistic takes.  For example, McDonalds cannot copyright or trademark the letter "M" but it can trademark the "Golden Arches" a unique stylized "M" that they use as signage to at all their locations.   If the name is a brand of a certain product such, then the name can be trademarked but only with respect to that product.   For example, if the Acme Wash-Master is a dish washing machine they can't sue Ace Wash Master, a unique dog bathing system, for using the name "Wash Master" since it's both styled different (Acme uses a dash between words.  ACE uses a space) and non-competitive product lines (most people would not wash dishes in a dog bathing device... and one would certainly hope that no dog owners ever said to themselves "Fido stinks and my tub is busted. The dish washer will do in a pinch!").

Comment: IIRC, it's even harder or impossible to trademark numbers at all, and for example that's why Intel started naming their CPUs (e.g. Pentium as a brand-name for 80586, where 80486 was only ever known as "486".)

Comment: Well some numbers themselves can be illegal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wo19Y4tw0l8